# How do I install the most recent Tensorflow (here: 2.2) on Windows when conda does not yet support it?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, tensorflow2.0

I have conda 4.8.3 and Python 3.7.4 on Windows 8.1.

I have tf 2.0.0 installed in a conda environment. How do I upgrade to 2.2.x?

Or, how do I just install 2.2.x in a conda environment?

Edit 1: pip install --upgrade tensorflow says: `Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in d:\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (2.1.0)`

but tf version is still 2.0.

Edit 2: conda install tensorflow==2.2.0 says:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

- tensorflow==2.2.0

I did have some luck [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376660/installing-tensorflow-2-gets-a-dll-failed-to-load-in-pywrap-tensorflow-py).

Edit 3:

```
(tf2) D:\ray\dev\covid-19>conda list -n tf2
# packages in environment at D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py37_0
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl
absl-py                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0
asn1crypto                1.0.1                    py37_0
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
astroid                   2.3.1                    py37_0
astropy                   3.2.1            py37he774522_0
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1
attrs                     19.2.0                     py_0
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
backports                 1.0                        py_2
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_2
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
beautifulsoup4            4.8.0                    py37_0
bitarray                  1.0.1            py37he774522_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
blosc                     1.16.3               h7bd577a_0
bokeh                     1.3.4                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h452e1ab_1
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
cachetools                4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2019.9.11                py37_0
cffi                      1.12.3           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py37_0
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h62dcd97_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3
contextlib2               0.6.0                      py_0
cryptography              2.7              py37h7a1dbc1_0
curl                      7.65.3               h2a8f88b_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.13          py37ha925a31_0
cytoolz                   0.10.0           py37he774522_0
dask                      2.5.2                      py_0
dask-core                 2.5.2                      py_0
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
dill                      0.3.1.1                  pypi_0    pypi
distributed               2.5.2                      py_0
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
fsspec                    0.5.2                      py_0
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.4.0            py37he774522_0
glob2                     0.7                        py_0
google-auth               1.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.1.8                      py_0
googleapis-common-protos  1.51.0                   pypi_0    pypi
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37hfa6e2cd_0
grpcio                    1.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imageio                   2.6.0                    py37_0
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        0.23                     py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.2            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.8.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0
joblib                    0.13.2                   py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
json5                     0.8.5                      py_0
jsonschema                3.0.2                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.3.3                    py37_1
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0
jupyterlab                1.1.4              pyhf63ae98_0
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0
keras                     2.3.1            py37h21ff451_0    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37ha925a31_0
krb5                      1.16.1               hc04afaa_7
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.2            py37he774522_0
libarchive                3.3.3                h0643e63_5
libcurl                   7.65.3               h2a8f88b_0
libgpuarray               0.7.6                hfa6e2cd_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.9.0                ha925a31_2
libmklml                  2019.0.5                      0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.11.2               h7bd577a_0
libpython                 2.1                      py37_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libssh2                   1.8.2                h7a1dbc1_0
libtiff                   4.0.10               hb898794_2
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
libxslt                   1.1.33               h579f668_0
llvmlite                  0.29.0           py37ha925a31_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.4.1            py37h1350720_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-binutils            2.25.1                        5
m2w64-bzip2               1.0.6                         6
m2w64-crt-git             5.0.0.4636.2595836               2
m2w64-gcc                 5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-ada             5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-fortran         5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-objc            5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-headers-git         5.0.0.4636.c0ad18a               2
m2w64-isl                 0.16.1                        2
m2w64-libiconv            1.14                          6
m2w64-libmangle-git       5.0.0.4509.2e5a9a2               2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-make                4.1.2351.a80a8b8               2
m2w64-mpc                 1.0.3                         3
m2w64-mpfr                3.1.4                         4
m2w64-pkg-config          0.29.1                        2
m2w64-toolchain           5.3.0                         7
m2w64-tools-git           5.0.0.4592.90b8472               2
m2w64-windows-default-manifest 6.4                           3
m2w64-winpthreads-git     5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-zlib                1.2.8                        10
mako                      1.1.0                      py_0
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37hc8f65d3_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py37he774522_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37h675688f_0
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0
more-itertools            7.2.0                    py37_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h74a9793_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.6.0                    py37_1
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
networkx                  2.3                        py_0
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
notebook                  6.0.1                    py37_0
numba                     0.45.1           py37hf9181ef_0
numexpr                   2.7.0            py37hdce8814_0
numpy                     1.16.5           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.16.5           py37hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  3.0.0                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_3
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0
packaging                 19.2                       py_0
pandas                    0.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0
partd                     1.0.0                      py_0
path.py                   12.0.1                     py_0
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    6.2.0            py37hdc69c19_0
pip                       20.0.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
pluggy                    0.13.0                   py37_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         2
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
promise                   2.3                      pypi_0    pypi
prompt_toolkit            2.0.10                     py_0
protobuf                  3.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.6.3            py37he774522_0
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37ha925a31_2
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37hfa6e2cd_9
pycurl                    7.43.0.3         py37h7a1dbc1_0
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0
pygpu                     0.7.6            py37h452e1ab_0
pylint                    2.4.2                    py37_0
pyodbc                    4.0.27           py37ha925a31_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.15.4           py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0
pytables                  3.5.2            py37h1da0976_1
pytest                    5.2.1                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.4.0                      py_0
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0
python                    3.7.4                h5263a28_0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0
pywavelets                1.0.3            py37h8c2d366_1
pywin32                   223              py37hfa6e2cd_1
pywinpty                  0.5.5                 py37_1000
pyyaml                    5.1.2            py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37ha925a31_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0
qtconsole                 4.5.5                      py_0
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0
rsa                       4.0                      pypi_0    pypi
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37hfa6e2cd_0
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37ha925a31_0
scikit-learn              0.21.3           py37h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                41.4.0                   py37_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
sklearn                   0.0                      pypi_0    pypi
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
soupsieve                 1.9.3                    py37_0
sphinx                    2.2.0                      py_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.3.9            py37he774522_0
sqlite                    3.30.0               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37h8c2d366_0
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0
tbb                       2019.4               h74a9793_0
tblib                     1.4.0                      py_0
tensorboard               2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-base           2.0.0           mkl_py37hd1d5974_0
tensorflow-datasets       2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metadata       0.21.1                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
theano                    1.0.4                    py37_0
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_0
tqdm                      4.36.1                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.2.1                      py_0
xlwings                   0.15.10                  py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade ...` ?

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35754) regarding installing `tf 2.1`. Not sure if the package you are looking for is available in conda yet.
If `conda install tensorflow==2.2.0` does not work I think you have to wait or provide the package by yourself.

Comment: @furas please see edit.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and `pip` installs for one Python but you run second Python. Check version  in pip `pip -V` and in python which you run `python -V`. Or use your Python to install it `python -m pip install --upgrade ....`

Comment: i have no idea how many pythons i have installed. pip 20.0.2 from D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7). python is still 3.7.4.

Comment: if you use command `python` to run code then use it also to install module - `python -m pip install --upgrade ....` - and it should install it in correct Python.

Comment: also gets: equirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in d:\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (2.1.0)

Comment: Please share the contents of the environment. (`conda list -n env_name`) _pip install --upgrade tensorflow_ Why, did you install TF through pip?

Comment: please see edfit. i used pip because on of the comments suggested it.

Comment: @RayTayek It’s probably a bad idea, especially since those packages are easily available from Conda. See https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment, for example. Your best bet is to start from scratch in a new environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are two methods

#### 1. Install into  virtual environment with

```
pip TensorFlow

virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
```

then you need to activate your new environment

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip list  # show packages installed within the virtual environment
this command for quit 
deactivate  # don't exit until you're done using TensorFlow
we finish by installing tensor 

pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

#### 2. Install in your system

```
python3 --version
pip3 --version
virtualenv --version
```

#### Ubuntu

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip

sudo pip3 install -U virtualenv  # system-wide install
```

then

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow  # install in $HOME
```

Comment: This question is about Conda, so why use virtualenv?

Answer (score 9):

TF 2.2.0 isn't available on conda yet.

Comment: as on June 16th 2020, Linux conda 2.2 is up, Windows is 2.1 and OSX is 2.0 https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow. This can lead to strange behaviors, watch out.

Comment: In such a case, wait, since conda is the recommended way to install and update TF, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040400/why-using-anaconda-environments-to-install-tensorflow-on-windows.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to install TF 2.2.0 now with either:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0
```

or

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

ONE IMPORTANT THING: for now, at least in my case, there is a major problem with the GPU version. The old one recognises my GPU with no issues, while the latest doesn't see it for some reason. I advise you to create, just in case, a new env so you won't need to reinstall everything later on.

EDIT by a reader:

Better do not use pip install at all if you can wait for the conda version to catch up. Using the pip installer is not recommended, even if it often offers a more recent version. Using pip will risk exactly the documented error here. And you do not need to create a new env with conda update, `conda update --all` will not harm your dependencies in your env. See [Why using Anaconda environments to install tensorflow on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040400/why-using-anaconda-environments-to-install-tensorflow-on-windows).

Comment: i get these errors with pip in an anoconda environment: ERROR: tensorflow 2.0.0 has requirement gast==0.2.2, but you'll have gast 0.3.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.0.0 has requirement tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0, but you'll have tensorboard 2.2.1 which is incompatible.

Comment: I presume you're trying to install 2.2.0 on the existing env. Have you tried creating a new one? Otherwise, I, unfortunately, won't be able to help as I didn't have any of these errors, not when I installed TF2.2.0 on an existing env with TF2.1.0 using the second method I wrote, nor when I created a completely new env. As I said, the only problem I have is that TF2.2.0 doesn't detect my GPU so it's useless to me. I'm waiting for the official Conda release and I think you should do the same or go away from Conda if you really need TF2.2. Cheers.

Comment: i cloned my base, activated it and tried pip. the real reason i want to updrade is that it might help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411185/import-tensorflow-module-is-slow-in-tensorflow-2?noredirect=1#comment107692111_59411185

Comment: where to list this? Need older version. Gpu. Google doesn't allow listing.

Comment: hi i need 2.2 version for windows with gpu. where can i find it?

Answer (score 1):

create new environment and use this command in jupyter notebook :

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.2-rc3
```

this version work on CPU or  GPU.

Comment: trying this. after a couple of hours, it's still uninstalling estimator. stay tuned.

Comment: @RayTayek Hope it is finished

Comment: @TouYou Does it install install the nightly build or stable build?

Comment: not sure if i resolved that. i dropped conda and went to venv's. got 2.4 working.

Answer (score 0):

**Its becasue your required tensorflow version is not available in you current python version.**
For Example: **python 3.9 doesn't has tensorflow 2.2.0**

I have faced this issue once, may this helps you.

Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31879558)