# How to install tensorflow==2.3.0

Tags: tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2

I would like to test some function in the new [tensorflow2.3](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-cpu/2.3.0rc2/) However, I am struggling with installation process.

I saw: [How do I install the most recent Tensorflow (here: 2.2) on Windows when conda does not yet support it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357038/how-do-i-install-tensorflow-2-2-in-windows)

I executed: `pip install --upgrade pip`

I got:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-cpu==2.3.0rc2 (from versions: 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-cpu==2.3.0rc2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please make sure pip is pointing to pip3 because tensorflow requires python3

```
pip --version


pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Indeed, it was pointing to python2.7. The upgrade allows me to get tf2.3 by pip install tensorflow-cpu==2.3.0rc2. Thanks again!

Comment: important to upgrade pip first; pip3 install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue, but had to *downgrade* python from 3.9 to 3.8.
Python 3.8 is [the latest version](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) that supports tensorflow 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

For some cases, you need to upgrade your pip version

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then install tensorflow 2.3.0 version