# Install Tensorflow 2.2 for Python 3.8 in Anaconda (Windows x64)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I've just installed the latest version of Anaconda for Windows x64 with Python 3.8 and would like to add the `tensorflow` module. 
According to [this website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/), `tensorflow 2.2.0` should be available.

However, my Anaconda only suggests `tensorflow 2.1.0` and fails to install it because it's not compatible with Python 3.8.

How can I install `tensorflow 2.2.0`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the most recent Tensorflow (here: 2.2) on Windows when conda does not yet support it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357038/how-do-i-install-the-most-recent-tensorflow-here-2-2-on-windows-when-conda-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you installed tensorflow2.1 using Conda it automatically installed cudnn 7.6.5 and CUDA Toolkit 10.1.243. These are compatible with tensorflow 2.2. Then use pip to install tensorflow 2.2 as shown below

```
pip install tensorflow ==2.2.0
```

Conda at this time can only install tensorflow up to 2.1 that is why you have to use pip. pip does not automatically install cudnn or the Cuda toolkit but you already have them installed when you install version 2.1 with Conda. Otherwise you would have to go through a more complicated  process to manually install cudnn and the toolkit. Some people have reported problems using python 3.8 with tensorflow. If you run into that create as seperate environment and install python 3.7, tensorflow 2.1 using conda, the tensorflow 2.2 using pip.

Answer (score 2):

For this you might want to downgrade the Python to `v3.7`. 
It is always a good practice to run TensorFlow in the lower-tested version of python. (Thats what I do.) And it just works as good as it would run in `Python 3.8`.

For this you might use the virtual environment using.
Create using:

```
conda create -n env_name python=3.7
```

And then just activate using:

```
conda activate env_name
```

And to install TensorFlow 2.2 just run:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

And once you are done, run:

```
conda deactivate
```

Comment: Does this actually address the issue?

Comment: yeah, after downgrading the python version, you can install TensorFlow 2.2 in anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

AnjaM,

I faced same problem. The other Conda page [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow) still reports that their latest TF  for Windows is 2.1.0. See screenshot below.

It may be a matter of days but I personally got tired of waiting and installed TF 2.3.0 with pip. 2.1.0 was throwing errors where 2.3.0 would work fine.
Tips for installation:

- do it in separate virtual environment
- install all other needed packages fist and then install TF with pip
- when updating other packages - don't let conda to downgrade TF.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.
So, I installed tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0 with 'pip'.
then installed cudann = 7.6.5 and cudatoolkit==10.1.243

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu=2.2.0

conda install cudatoolkit==10.1.243
conda install cudnn==7.6.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add conda-forge as one of the package sources with this command:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Once you do this, just update the package index and you'll be able to see the latest versions of all packages.